# How do I connect plots of summary statistics and raw data with bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset which I'm plotting summary statistics of, and I would like to be able to select an interesting point and plot the underlying raw data in a separate subfigure. The code below can be run from a jupyter notebook to see what the outputs should look like. Ideally I would be able to click the point near (1, 10) in the first plot, and see raw data clustered around 10 in the second plot.

The commented out code near the bottom was my attempt at defining the callback, but I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how taptools and callbacks are supposed to work. How do I tell bokeh that it should call a specific python routine with specific arguments (based on the point I clicked on) and then reload the second figure?

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, widgets, HoverTool, TapTool

output_notebook()

class RawPlot():
    def __init__(self, fig, col, raw):
        self.fig = fig
        self.raw = raw
        self.circ = self.fig.circle(x='index', y='raw', size=1,
                                    source=ColumnDataSource(raw[col].reset_index()))
    # ideally I would have a callback to RawPlot.update to change the underlying data
    def update(self, col):
        self.circ.data_source = ColumnDataSource(self.raw[col].reset_index())

# generate the example data
rawdat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1024, 4)) + np.arange(4)*10, 
                      columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(s, 'raw') for s in ascii_lowercase[:4]]))
# compute summary statistics and show in a bokeh figure
stats = rawdat.describe().T.reset_index()
pstat = figure()
pstat.circle(x='index', y='mean', source=ColumnDataSource(stats), size=12)

# show the raw data of the first column
praw = figure()
rawplot = RawPlot(praw, 'a', rawdat)
# this was my attempt at being able to change which column's raw data was plotted. It failed
# taptool = pstat.select(type=TapTool)
# taptool.callback = rawplot.update("@level_0")
show(gridplot([[pstat, praw]]))
```

Comment: Is this a Bokeh server app? Then you want to use an `on_change` handler for the data source to set the callback. The `.callback` attribute is only to set a `CustomJS` callback, i.e. a JavaScript callback which by definition can never invoke or execute any python code. If you want to respond to selections or widget events with *python* code, you have to use the Bokeh server (enabling that use-case is its primary purpose).

Comment: This is not a bokeh server app yet. I just found the relevant part of the bokeh documentation that tells me I can't just do everything in a notebook.

Comment: An alternative in the notebook is `push_notebook` http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyter-interactors That example uses widgets, but you can just use `push_notebook` to update data without widgets, too.

Comment: That seems like it would be the solution, but I'm still not figuring out what attribute of the TapTool actually changes when a selection is made (which I would need as an argument to on_change).

Comment: No attribute on `TapTool` :) Selections are recorded on the data sources, so that is what you would put an `on_change` handler on, for the `selection` attribute of the data source. The reason for this is that lots of kinds of tools can make selections (box, lasso, tap, etc.) and the data source is the one place that makes sense for them to update

Comment: That *does* make sense. I've got a prototype that seems to do what I want with `bokeh serve foo.py`. It doesn't seem to work with the notebooks though (code in answer). Thanks a lot for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles the interactions the way I wanted. It functions with the bokeh server well enough for the test case. Running the code from a notebook doesn't have the same interactivity though (selecting data in `pstat` doesn't update the data in the `praw`). Thus `output_notebook` and `push_notebook` are commented out.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, gridplot
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, widgets, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxSelectTool
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, push_notebook, output_server
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

# generate the example data
rawdat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1024, 4)) + np.arange(4)*10, 
                      columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(s, 'raw') for s in ascii_lowercase[:4]]))
# compute summary statistics and show in a bokeh figure
stats = rawdat.describe().T.reset_index()
statsource = ColumnDataSource(stats[['mean']])

TOOLS = [TapTool(), BoxSelectTool()]
pstat = figure(tools=TOOLS)
pstat.circle(x='index', y='mean', source=statsource, size=12)

# show the raw data of the first column
praw = figure()
col = rawdat.columns.levels[0][0]
rawsource = ColumnDataSource(rawdat[col].reset_index())
circ = praw.circle(x='index', y='raw', size=1,
                   source=rawsource)

# update the raw data_source when a new summary is chosen
def update(attr, old, new):
    ind = new['1d']['indices'][0]
    col = rawdat.columns.levels[0][ind]
    rawsource.data['raw'] = rawdat[col].values.ravel()
    # push_notebook()
statsource.on_change('selected', update)

# serve the figures
output_server("foo")
# output_notebook()
show(gridplot([[pstat, praw]]))
```